# Apple Push Notification not received sometimes (JavaPNS)

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, payload

I'm making a chat with a notification service. Sometimes that the notifications dont arrives to my device. I'm using JavaPNS, so my code isn't very complex, but when I send a lot of messages very quickly (about 10) from one device to another, I don't receive all the notifications. Some of them are lost in the way (generally one of two).

Here is my code:

```
PushNotificationPayload payload = PushNotificationPayload.complex();
payload.addAlert("Name : text"); payload.addSound("default");
payload.addBadge(1); 
payload.addCustomDictionary("type", NOTIF_MESSAGE);
Push.payload(payload, "******.p12", "password", false, URI);
```

Comment: according to apple documentation notification not arrive very frequentaly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK.

> Important: Because **delivery is not guaranteed**, you should not depend
>   on the remote-notifications facility for delivering critical data to
>   an application via the payload. And never include sensitive data in
>   the payload. You should use it only to notify the user that new data
>   is available.

-[Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html).

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't guarantee that ALL MESSAGES are ever delivered. The documentation says:

> delivery of notifications is “best effort” and is not guaranteed.